# .CreateQuery() Function not available to me

Tags: sqlite, uwp, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I'm currently playing around with Azure Easy Tables and SQL following this guide: https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/

Everything has gone well so far (or at least I was able to easily modify portions of the code to work) until I got to this line : await coffeeTable.PullAsync("allCoffees", coffeeTable.CreateQuery());

In my UWP project I am unable to use the .CreateQuery() function and no amount of googling/binging has been able to clarify why this is. Clearly it worked this way at one point or it wouldn't have made it's way into that blog but I'm guessing something changed though I can't find anyone else who has needed this function and been unable to get it to work.

Here is my code with it implemented:

```
public class AzureDataService
{
    public MobileServiceClient MobileService { get; set; }
    IMobileServiceSyncTable productTable;

    public async Task<IEnumerable> GetProducts()
    {
    }

    public async Task AddProduct(bool madeAtHome)
    {
    }



    public async Task Intialize()
    {
        //Create our client
        MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("http://ommited.azurewebsites.net");

        const string path = "syncstore.db";
        //setup our local sqlite store and intialize our table
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
        store.DefineTable<Product>();
        await MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler());

        //Get our sync table that will call out to azure
        productTable = MobileService.GetSyncTable<Product>(); 
    }

    public async Task SyncProducts()
    {
        //pull down all latest changes and then push current coffees up
        await productTable.PullAsync("allProducts", productTable.CreatQuery());
        await MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
    }
}
```

}

So I guess my question is whether or not this function has been removed and if so how do I generate the string that .PullAsync(string queryid, string query) is looking for as it's second parameter (I'd also love to know what exactly that string represents). If the function still exists (and is usable within UWP) what nugget package or using statement do I need to access it?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by changing `IMobileServiceSyncTable` to `IMobileServiceSyncTable<Product>`.